# How do I find the qty of products ordered for a specific attribute option in Ubercart?

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, e-commerce, ubercart

I'm trying to make a custom order summary module for Ubercart/Drupal that will display information something like this:

```
       S   M   L
Prod1  10  20  40
Prod2  0   15  0
```

where `S`, `M`, and `L` are options for a custom attribute (size in this case), and the numbers are the quantities ordered of each product of each size.

I notice that the selected option is specified in the `data` field for the product in the `uc_order_products` table of the database. I can figure out all the arithmetic and everything if someone can tell me a good way of finding all the `uc_order_products` rows which contain a specific option for a specific attribute. I'd even be happy with just a simple way to return the `data` field as an object or associative array.

Alternate solutions involving Ubercart's API are also welcome, but from what I saw in the docs, there don't really appear to be functions for this kind of thing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer in PHP's own [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php). I'd never had any experience with serialization in PHP, so I didn't recognize the format when I saw it.